# How can I hide actual YouTube video URLin codeingiter from user

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, iframe

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" 
src="<?php echo 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/oLuKopMbl9k'; ?>" 
frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; 
autoplay; 
encrypted-media; 
gyroscope; 
picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

How can I hide actual YouTube video URL in codeingiter / PHP from user,

I have hide the "src" attribute value so user no one can directly copy and paste it.

Comment: does there any method in javascript @Areg

Comment: i take that back lol

Comment: What for, don't YouTube videos have a "YouTube" link to the video at the bottom that users can click?

Comment: I have only one question...Why?

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, its not possible to hide a URL from user, user will always be able to download the video as long he can watch it in browser

EDIT: forget to mention you can try to use other platforms, but with you tube is not possible to hide as you can click on the logo and open in YouTube

Comment: Not really an answer, more of a comment

Comment: i would love to comment but i cant comment as im a new user

Comment: We've all been there, only answer question with "real" answers

Comment: Hey guys please try to help not just comment on comment